# Remove title slide from Rmarkdown beamer presentation

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

I feel silly for asking but I am not able to remove the title slide from my beamer presentation generated with R Markdown. I prefer to make the title slide on my own and not use the default. Thank you in advance.

Here is a MWE:

```
---
title: "Some Title"
author:  "tlmoore"
output: beamer_presentation
latex_engine: lualatex
classoption: "aspectratio=169, 10pt"
---

## First slide

Some text here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the `classoption` you can add `titlepage: false` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the appropriate beamer template to make the title page whatever you want:

```
---
title: "Some Title"
author:  "tlmoore"
output: beamer_presentation
latex_engine: lualatex
classoption: "aspectratio=169, 10pt"
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{title page}{make your own titel page}
---

## First slide

Some text here
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Sorry it took so long to get back.

Comment: @tlmoore You're welcome! No worries about the time, I've written answers to which the author of the question only reacted after 7 years :)